# R ifelse changed factor value into index

Tags: r, data.table, categorical-data

I met a weird problem when I am using R, I'm using data.table:

Here, when I tried to convert those Province has count under 500 to "Other", the output changes the top count Provinces into index number

```
df <- fact_data[,.N,Province][N >= 500]$Province
df
fact_data[,Province := ifelse(Province %in% df, fact_data$Province, "Other")]
fact_data[,.N,Province][order(-N)]
```

**Output:**
[image: p1]

But, this method worked well on those factor variables which values are in numeric format. For example, instead of using Province, if I use BranchNumber, the values look like "1", "3", I got the input like this, which is good:

[image: p2]

Do you know, why this happened and how to resolve the problem?

Comment: This is probably a side effect of `ifelse` which has a bad habit of changing the class of its return value unpredictably. Try `fact_data[ Province %in% df, Province := "Other" ]` instead.

Comment: Awesome! It works. I just need to change the previous logic to `df <- fact_data[,.N,Province][N < 500]$Province`, then with `fact_data[ Province %in% df, Province := "Other" ]`, I got what I want. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Cool. Fyi, you can also negate it like `!( Province %in% df )`, thought that might make the code more confusing (compared to changing the inequality).

Comment: It's a great learning! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a side effect of `ifelse`, which has a bad habit of changing the class of its return value unpredictably. Try this instead:

```
fact_data[ !( Province %in% df ), Province := "Other" ]
```

Generally, I would recommend working with character vectors as data.table columns instead of factors whenever possible.